# How to get hold of a auto generated number with childByAutoId in firebase swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, swift4

I created a node inside my firebase database using childByAutoId. Now I want to delete it with swift. How do I get a reference to this auto generated number? I am thinking about using this code :

```
func deleteAction(at indexPath : IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
        let vinyl = self.vinyls[indexPath.row]
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { fatalError() }

        Database.database().reference().child("vinyls").child(userID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, _) in
            <#code#>
        })


    }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the value with

```
Database.database().reference().child("vinyls").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

   let ref = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]

   // now you get ref where key is the auto-generated id and value is the dictionary you set with setValue before 

}
```